# Using readline in python3 (input) pressing arrows will remove text from the input

Tags: command-line, keyboard, python3, readline

My input code is:

```
import readline
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
readline.parse_and_bind('set editing-mode vi')

while True:
     c = input('INPUT> ')
```

(It is a little piece of test code to test readline.)

When i type abc ENTER Hello, World! ENTER and 2x arrow up instead of

```
INPUT>abc
```

It is `INabc`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

(I already tried commenting out the readline.parse_and_bind's I also use updated python3 and updated my readline using pip3, which also it up to date. And my readline is for python3. And everything is up to date!)

Comment: Works correctly for me on 17.10. Which version of Ubuntu do you have? If an older one, probably it's been fixed in python3 or readline.

Comment: Sound more like a programming issue though probably no off topic here.

Comment: I mean that you will likely get better answers over on [SO] than here.

Comment: I think this problem is more related to the terminal and ubuntu

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? Sounds like the problem may have to do with *that*.

Comment: gnome-terminal, bash

Comment: Have you tried it with a different terminal emulator and/or shell? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10, yes Xterm and TTY (The raw).

Comment: How are you running this script? Just with `python3 program.py`?

Comment: yes, just python3 test.py